# Is fine-grained grid control possible?

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, metapost, grids

I want to make a variety of checklists which are essentially based on a grid layout.  I care about having fine-grained control over the exact placement of labels and boxes.  I do not care about paragraphs, hypenation, equations, or anything like that which I know TeX is very good at.

If TeX can do this, then I think it may be a good fit for my needs, but I do not know the whethers or hows.  I know about Tikz but it doesn't give me enough fine-grained control.  Maybe PGF would be suitable, but I never understood where Tikz ends and PGF begins.  If I fail to find a way to solve my problem using TeX I will probably explore SVG and PostScript.

Here are some examples of the kind of thing I would like to do that I pulled from an image search for "checklist"

- https://studenttechportfolio.wikispaces.com/file/view/checklist.png/34343465/checklist.png
- http://checklisttemplate911.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/checklist-template12.jpg
- http://img.docstoccdn.com/thumb/orig/72289360.png
- http://www.bimmerfest.com/forums/attachment.php?attachmentid=88940&stc=1
- http://theorganisedhousewife.com.au/shop/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/conference-checklist.jpg
- http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-piQobSY-8Mw/Tcihq580IgI/AAAAAAAAAgE/Fd0AQD1e69Y/s1600/Operator_Page_1.jpg
- http://www.dbh.govt.nz/UserFiles/Image/Publications/building/weathertightness/remediation-checklist-2.gif
- http://spxcooling.com/images/M92-1447C-s.jpg

Can TeX give me this kind of fine-grained control of grid layout?  If so, is PGF a good technology for it?  If not, how would these kind of results best be obtained?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I think a combination of the `tikz` and [`tikzpagenodes`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.pdf) packages should do the trick.

Comment: I would definitely look at ConTeXt (or ConTeXt + Metafun), maybe even ask this question on the ConTeXt mailing list.

Comment: Short answer is "yes."  If you want a longer answer you probably need to refine your question. :-)

Comment: Well, "How could I do it?".  What TeX commands or packages should I look at?

Comment: Tom - People who care about Indesign-style grid layout are more likely to use Context than Latex, I think.  Take a look at chapter 3 of the Context manual (particularly section 3.4, also sections 4.10 and 11 are relevant): http://www.ctex.org/documents/context/cont-enp.pdf

Comment: The conference checklist can easily be set in Context using so-called HTML tables: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/TABLE